# the program is not working when the value in flag variable in the last statement is not 0

Tags: python

Why is it that if I remove the last `flag = 0` statement, not all the numbers are output?

```
a=[]

for i in range (100,1001):
    if i%5== 0 and i%6==0:
        flag=0
        a.append(i)

for j in range(len(a)):
    print(a[j], end=" ")
    flag+=1
    if flag==10:
        print("")
        flag=0
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: why is the for loop terminating when I delete the last statement (flag=0)

Comment: Please update your question with your current output, plus your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is being buffered, so you need a final `print` at the end.

```
for j in range(len(a)):
    print(a[j], end=" ")
    flag+=1
    if flag==10:
        print("")
print()
```

Alternatively, set `flush` to `True`.

```
for j in range(len(a)):
    print(a[j], end=" ", flush=True)
    flag+=1
    if flag==10:
        print("")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering
I want to understand more about buffering, can u suggest to me any source from where I can learn more about buffering or a similar concept

Comment: @ayush You can look at [this](https://realpython.com/python-print/#buffering-print-calls) and [this](https://blog.finxter.com/what-is-python-output-buffering-and-how-to-disable-it/).

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
a = [str(i) for i in range(100, 1001) if i % 5 == 0 and i % 6 == 0]
while len(a) > 10:
    print(' '.join(a[:11]), flush=True)
    a = a[11:]
print(' '.join(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work if you remove `flag=0' is because you do not create the flag variable.
This can be fixed by saying

````
a=[] 
for i in range (100,1001): 
    if i%5== 0 and i%6==0: 
        ``` //flag=0
        a.append(i)
```add flag=0 here
flag=0
for j in range(len(a)): 
    print(a[j], end=" ") 
    flag+=1 
    if flag==10: 
        print("") 
        flag=0
````

I hope this answers your question

Comment: yes its working for me as well but I want to understand why the loop is being terminated when I delete last statement(flag=0)